# Is it possible to send a DocuSign template via sms delivery?

Tags: docusignapi

As the title suggests, I'm wondering how I can send a template defined within Docusign via SMS delivery. However, I'm only seeing documentation on how to send a document from storage outside of docusign. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please check (accept) the best answer for your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for the recipients specified in a template, your API program can choose for them to be notified by SMS only, SMS and email, or email only.

- This [live example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Template%20with%20SMS-only%20delivery) uses a template to send an SMS-only notification to a recipient.
- This [live example via the API Request Builder](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Template%20with%20email%20and%20SMS%20delivery) uses a template to send SMS and email notifications to a recipient.

If you want to know how to replace a template's document with a different document when you send the envelope, here's a [live example](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Use%20a%20new%20document%20with%20a%20template) for that.

The API Request Builder can create the examples in C#, Java, PHP, Node.JS, Ruby, or Python.